# Twilio Studio - Send and wait for and reply - how can I loop until desired user input

Tags: twilio, twilio-studio, twilio-flow

I'm sending text suggestions for my users using Twilio. A user can respond with a "Confirm", "Decline" or send a freetext response, which I then parse and make changes accordingly (using a Make HTTP request widget), and send the new suggestion back to the user.

Is there a way to create a "while" loop for this process? every time the user doesn't respond with a "Confirm"/"Decline" - send its input to the make request widget.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You could do a while look by combining a [Set Variables Widget](https://www.twilio.com/docs/studio/widget-library/set-variables) with a [Split Based On... Widget](https://www.twilio.com/docs/studio/widget-library/split-based-on).  Similarly to what is shown in this diagram:
[image]

However, I think in your case the **no reply outlet of the [Send & Wait For Reply Widget](https://www.twilio.com/docs/studio/widget-library/send-wait-reply) should do the job as well.**

> You can configure a timeout to wait for the response, after which we will assume "No Reply" and transition accordingly. You can use this to send a followup reminder message, trigger an outgoing voice call, or update your database with no response.

Comment: Thanks, but it's not exactly my use case.. I'm trying to get the user's feedback until they'll either "approve" or "decline". i started testing out with 2 "Set variables" widgets (one for the initial user SMS reply, and one for the user's reply after I make changes). doing this is allowing me to have some sort of a loop. i do wish there was a simpler solution though

Comment: I'm afraid this is the tradeoff you have to do with No Code Tools like Studio. You can do it without writing and hosting a single line of code but it might take a few widgets.